# Emacs Tramp ssh double hop

Tags: emacs, ssh, tramp

Could somebody please help me setup Emacs Tramp to do a double hop?
I want to work on machine2.abc.def.edu to which I can connect only through machine1.abc.def.edu. My username is myname, on both machines same.

I've tried to add .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist
          '("\\`machine2\\.abc\\.def\\.edu\\'"
            "\\`myname\\'"
            "/ssh:machine1\\.abc\\.def\\.edu:"))
```

This is my best guess interpretation of what's in the manual. Then I do:
C-x C-f /ssh:machine2.abc.def.edu
or:
C-x C-f /ssh:rsuhada@machine2.abc.def.edu

But both give:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Process *tramp/scpc ssh* exited abnormally with code 255
```

And my Aquamacs can't be quitted and have to killed from shell... There is a 2 years thread here with same question. I've tried the answer from there:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist
          '("machine2.abc.def.edu"
            nil
            "/ssh:myname@machine1.abc.def.edu:"))
```

With same results... also for all combinations I could come up with... Remote editing on machine1.abc.def.edu works fine, though.

Comment: Looks related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715855/how-can-i-use-emacs-tramp-to-double-hop-ssh though not sure if that answers your question

Comment: Yes this is exactly the post I refered to in my post (i.e. solution 2). It doesn't work for me.... the netcat solution is also not feasible for me...

Comment: You might want to customize the `tramp-verbose` variable to see if you can get more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, let's try something different then, without opening a tunnel. How about the following in your .emacs file:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist 
             '("\\`machine2\\'" 
               nil 
               "/ssh:%u@machine1.abc.def.edu:"))
```

This is different from the code you found in the forum post in two points:

1. it adds ticks around the target host
   name (Emacs regexp syntax to avoid
   matching partial names)
2. it uses only
   the subdomain name in the target
   host (you reported in a comment
   below that you cannot ssh to
   machine2 when you use the full
   domain name)

Does that help when you try to access a file on machine2?

Comment: Wow! It works!!! Thanks so much Thomas! It's quite unbelievable for me that there are people here willing and able to help strangers! :) Thanks very very much. For posteriority if somebody has similar troubles: to login: C-x C-f myname@machine2   (i.e. no domains)

Comment: Great! (I think this is particular to your local setup, though).

Answer (score 10):

The answer it to use the [ssh_proxy](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config) command available in ssh_config. Documented [here](http://benno.id.au/blog/2006/06/08/ssh_proxy_command) and [here](http://www.statusq.org/archives/2008/07/03/1916/). Basically you create a config file in your ssh folder that you can write shortcuts in. One of your shortcuts is to use a proxy through another end point. All of your shortcuts work for any tool that uses ssh including git and emacs.

```
Host endpoint2
     User myusername
     HostName mysite.com
     Port 3000
     ProxyCommand ssh endpoint1 nc -w300 %h %p

Host endpoint1
     User somename
     HostName otherdomainorip.com
     Port 6893
```

In this example running `ssh endpoint2` will automatically hop through endpoint1.

Comment: Haven't tried it since the above solution worked, but thank ou very much for replying. Might be useful in future!

Comment: Note: I had to use "User" and not "Username" (in endpoint1 example) and I had to use "HostName" and not "Host" for both.

Answer (score 2):

Set up an ssh tunnel from machine1 to machine2 (assuming that sshd runs on port 22 on machine2):

```
machine1.abc.def.edu> ssh -f -N -L 2222:localhost:22 machine2.abc.def.edu
```

Then either connect to machine2 from Emacs like this:

```
/ssh:machine1.abc.def.edu#2222
```

or add the following line to your .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist
             '("\\`machine2\\.abc\\.def\\.edu\\'" nil
               "/tunnel:machine1.abc.def.edu#2222:"))
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives the same error. I've checked and the port is indeed 22. Tried both the /ssh: and adding the snippet to .emacs - no joy...

Comment: That sucks! Can you connect to machine2 from the shell by running `ssh -p 2222 machine1.abc.def.edu`?

Comment: Nope... although I'm bit confused, what you meant: on my laptop both ssh -p 2222 machine1.abc.def.edu and ssh -p 2222 machine2.abc.def.edu give "Connection refused". ssh machine1.abc.def.edu works fine.

Comment: I've noticed you added -f -L flags in your original reply. This doesn't work for me. The only thing that works is: machine1.abc.def.edu> ssh -L 2222:localhost:22 machine2 - i.e. if I add the domain .abc.def.edu it complains ("uudecode failed"), the same if I add the additional flags.

Comment: I've added `-f -N`, but they are optional. Is machine1 behind a firewall? It seems that you can reach port 22 on machine1 but not port 2222... Just to be clear, what I meant was you first login on machine1 and establish the tunnel with `ssh -L 2222:localhost:22 machine2`. Then from your laptop you try to do `ssh -p 2222 machine1.abc.def.edu`.

Comment: OK, yes this is exactly what I thought/did. Not sure about the firewall but it is possible... I do not have root access to either of the machines and just generally would prefer not to setup a tunnel. I thought that the proxy approach of tramp should be able to handle this...