# emacs tramp double-hop ssh earlier solutions just dont work

Tags: emacs, ssh, elisp, remote-access, tramp

Problem Statement:

Connect to machineB (jupiter) via creta@recog.vision.uni-bonn.de. My problem is closest to link 1 below. However, none of the info in the links make it work. To make the matters worse, emacs -debug-init produces no helpful info...atleast for an Emacs newbie such as myself.

One such debug info:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error:
>    (void-variable tramp-default-proxies-alist)
>     add-to-list(tramp-default-proxies-alist ("\\'jupiter\\'" nil "/ssh:creta@recog.vision.uni-bonn.de:"))
>     eval-buffer(# nil "/home/creta/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 159
>     load-with-code-conversion("/home/creta/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/creta/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
>     load("/home/creta/.emacs.d/init" t t)
>     #[0 "\205\262

Could the hyphen in the domain (uni-bonn) make a difference? I even tried with uni-bonn  and other combinations but it doesn't make a difference.

I can use tramp to ssh to creta@recog.... by C-x C-f /ssh:creta@recog.vision.uni-bonn.de: RET PASSWORD...but later I do not know how to ssh further into jupiter which is my workstation.

I have followed the advice here:

Link 1: [How can I use Emacs Tramp to double hop ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715855/how-can-i-use-emacs-tramp-to-double-hop-ssh?rq=1)

Link 2: [Open file via SSH and Sudo with Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs)

Link 3: [Emacs Tramp ssh double hop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847814/emacs-tramp-ssh-double-hop)

Link 4: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.tramp/7578

Link 5: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Multi_002dhops.html

It would be great if this annoying thing gets solved.

Thanks a lot. Have a great day!

EDIT 1: I dont mind if I need to ssh twice (first into domain and then workstation) though I dont know if its a good idea. ability to work with files as if local in emacs (with its diredplus and other goodies) is a nice feature.

EDIT 2: I am using Emacs 24.2 on a Ubuntu machine (Natty 11.04 --> should update soon) if that helps.

Comment: Note that with the shiny new Emacs 24.3, something analogous to (but more robust than) the old [multi:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/742667/324105) method has been implemented/restored. See http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Ad_002dhoc-multi_002dhops (or if you're using 24.3, `C-h i g (tramp) Ad-hoc multi-hops RET`).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I was planning to upgrade in April. This is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you mentioned is caused by TRAMP not being loaded before you try to configure it. Try using something like this:

```
(require 'tramp)
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist ...)
```

Or (better in terms of loading time, but more subject to tricky quoting-related bugs):

```
(eval-after-load "tramp"
   '(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist ...))
```

Comment: sweet! That did the trick. my uni login server is down for the past 2 hours but double hop ssh works elsewhere. With (setq tramp-default-method "ssh"), I need to only C-x C-f /user@host: RET password and I am through. Thanks a ton! Its strange, I spent almost 3 hours on this. Should learn to debug elisp code better. any tips?

Comment: I don't have any fancy tip for you... I guess elisp is like any other language: the best way to learn is to practice. I, for example, really started learning elisp when I began customizing and extending for my own needs.