# Emacs Tramp - How to edit files using Tramp as another user in a remote host?

Tags: emacs, tramp

I have only one user (say "goodk") that can accept SSH connections. So, I am not able to use Tramp to edit files which are accessible to other users than the one that accepts SSH connection. How can I achieve this?

How I do this currently:

I use terminal. From terminal I login to user "goodk". Then I switch user using `su` or `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked:
[How can I use Emacs Tramp to double hop ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715855/how-can-i-use-emacs-tramp-to-double-hop-ssh)
or
http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/000983.html

or
http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/366

Comment: But how will any of this help the user that owns the file does not allow ssh and the file is not accessible by other users?

Comment: Hemal Pandya: Because tramp provides `su` and `sudo` methods.

Answer (score 0):

To the remote server the files are being read/written by the user that connects via ssh. If the files to be modified are owned by a different user then they will need to be readable/writable by the ssh user.