# tramp mode in emacs via login server (multihop ssh)

Tags: emacs, ssh, tramp

how to accomplish a multihop ssh session in emacs as in the following example,

```
ssh -t username@login-server -t ssh username@my-institute-computer
```

using the tramp mode? M-x f RET and then "/ssh: -t ..." seems not to be correct

Thank you for your help!

---

Edit:
It seems that adding

```
Host my-institute-computer
ProxyCommand ssh login-server nc my-institute-computer 22
```

to ~/.ssh/config makes the input in emacs possible where I get asked twice for a password. However, now I receive "Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)". Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation? http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Multi_002dhops.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution for me was using emacs with

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs/tramp/lisp/")
  (require 'tramp)
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist
         '("destiny.server" nil "/ssh:username@login.server:"))
```

added in the .emacs file (as suggested in [How can I use Emacs Tramp to double hop ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715855/how-can-i-use-emacs-tramp-to-double-hop-ssh)).

First, I had the problem that my tramp-version was not supporting tramp-default-proxies-alist. After updating it (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tramp/) everything worked fine. Now it's enough to M-x f RET and then "/ssh:username@destiny.server:" to enter the remote server behind the login-server.