# Why am I unable to use emacs to open remote file using tramp?

Tags: emacs, ssh, tramp, ssh-agent

I am attempting to open a remote file, using a double hop (through a gateway) with ssh keys and key forwarding.

The command I give emacs:

```
ssh:user@gateway|ssh:otheruser@desthost:~/myfile.txt
```

And I keep getting the below output instead of the file:

```
Use M-x make-directory RET RET to create the directory and its parents
```

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16410046/113848), you need a slash sign at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you, of course it was something stupid.